# Difficulty installing AVbin for pyglet on a raspberry pii

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, pyglet

I made a simple music player using pyglet with the goal of making my raspberry pi a small music player (for a project).  Though my program runs fine on windows, I am having trouble getting it to install/recognise AVbin on the pi (running raspbian).

I've tried the suggestions in this stack overflow thread, but to no avail

[Python pyglet AVBin - How to install AVBin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302873/python-pyglet-avbin-how-to-install-avbin?rq=1)

No matter what method I've tried for installing AVbin, I get the error.

> WAVEFormatException: AVbin is required to decode compressed media

- Initially I tried downloading the latest 32 bit version from the
  website and went to the properties to allow it to be executed. 
  However, when executed in terminal, it runs for about a half second
  and then closes, seemingly doing nothing.
- I've also tried downloading an older version (v8) from their github
  in the form of a tar.  I extracted the tar, cd into the folder, chmod
  +x the install file, and ran it.  This worked and installed a 'libavbin.so' file into my usr/lib folder, but I still get the same
  error when run my python program.

At this point, I don't know whether it is not installed correctly, or possibly that it just doesn't know where to look for the AVbin reference.