# Installing Avbin on raspberry pi 3b

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, pyglet, debian-jessie

I have trouble installing avbin on my raspberry pi3 with jessie.
The command doesn't work:

```
sudo apt-get install libavbin-dev libavbin0
```

It says that is unable to locate.
I have manually downloaded version 10 and 8 and neither one works.
Pythons shows that cannot find the  library.
Any suggestions please?

This post didn't help me much

> [Python pyglet AVBin - How to install AVBin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302873/python-pyglet-avbin-how-to-install-avbin)

Update:
My sys path:

> > sys.path ['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']

and:

```
> usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet/media $ ls -l
```

total 180

```
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 19846 May 13 14:07 avbin.py
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 15458 May 13 14:07 avbin.pyc 
  -drwxr-sr-x 5 root staff 4096> May 13 14:07 drivers 
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 46363 May 13 14:07 init.py
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 53881 May 13 14:07 init.pyc 
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 6446 May 13 14:07 procedural.py 
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 5762 May> 13 14:07 procedural.pyc 
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 8107 May 13 14:07 riff.py 
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root staff 8331 May 13 14:07 riff.pyc
```

In /usr/lib I have:

> `libavbin.so 
>   libavbin.so.7 
>   libavbin.so.8`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27151530/929999

Comment: Tried, didn't work. It cannot find the library

Comment: `pyglet.lib.load_library('avbin')` didn't work? Then your check your `sys.path` variable and give us the paths, and show us a `ls  -l /path/to/where/avbin/is/` so we can confirm that avbin is actually accessible from Python, `-l` here is important so we can see the access rights.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the inner workings of avbin and where it needs to be. But mine resides under `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyglet/media/sources/avbin.py` and also `/usr/lib/libavbin.so` just like yours.

Comment: In usr/lib/python2.7 i don't have either pyglet or avbin or folder site-packages

Comment: @Torxed It is posible that pyglet is not installed correctly?